# How to show tootlip for steparea series of the telerik chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, telerik

Not able to get the tooltip for the StepArea Series. Its working for Bar series but StepAreaSeries is having a problem.

Code is as below.

```
var limitSeries = new StepAreaSeries
                {
                    CategoryBinding = new GenericDataPointBinding<ChartDataItem, string> { ValueSelector = v => v.Name },
                    CombineMode = ChartSeriesCombineMode.Stack,
                    ValueBinding = new GenericDataPointBinding<ChartDataItem, decimal?> { ValueSelector = v => v.Limit },
                    RisersPosition = StepSeriesRisersPosition.OnTicks
                };
                limitSeries.SetBinding(ChartSeries.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding(nameof(ChartDataItems)) { Source = this });
                limitSeries.SetValue(ChartAnimationUtilities.CartesianAnimationProperty, CartesianAnimation.Rise);
                limitSeries.TooltipTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["tttt"];                
                ChartSeriesSource.Add(limitSeries);
```

XAML

```
<controls:CartesianChart.Behaviors>
       <telerik:ChartTooltipBehavior />
</controls:CartesianChart.Behaviors>

<DataTemplate x:Key="tttt" DataType="charting:CategoricalDataPoint">
```

Answer (score 0):

Defined the PointTemplate , and then I was able to see the tooltip.

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:StepAreaSeries">
                    <Setter Property="PointTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Height="10" Width="10" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Issue is it cannot take the actual height and width dynamically as in barseries.